# How do I capture a specific SQL Server Error In Access VBA That Is Missing the Access Error Code?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, error-handling

I have a login form in Access that sends the username and pwd to an ODBC connection string to connect to a SQL Server (Express) onsite.  If they type the credentials in wrong I'd like a custom msgbox to come up rather than these 4 window messages from SQL Server and Access freaking out telling the user they didn't type something in correctly.  Since there isn't an Access error message in the first two I'm not sure how to intercept them and put something there in it's place.

Here is the error handling I have, which normally works for me with everything, but not for SQL Server:

```vb
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
'Stop
On Error GoTo Err_Login

    Dim varUserName As String
    Dim varPassword As String
    Dim vardim As String
    Dim varCreds As String

    varUserName = Me.txtUserName
    varPassword = Nz(Me.txtPassword, vbNullString)
    varCreds = "UID=" & varUserName & ";PWD=" & varPassword

    strConnection = "ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=serverip\database;" & varCreds & ";APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;DATABASE=database"

    Dim dbCurrent As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set dbCurrent = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set qdf = dbCurrent.CreateQueryDef("")

    Dim td As TableDef

    strsql = "SELECT * FROM ActiveTablesToLink WHERE LinkFlag = -1 And DatabaseName = 'database'"

    Set recLocal = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)

    recLocal.MoveLast
    recLocal.MoveFirst

    strRecCount = recLocal.RecordCount

    If strRecCount > 0 Then

        Do While Not recLocal.EOF

        stLocalTableName = recLocal!LocalTableName
        stRemoteTableName = recLocal!SSTableName

            Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, strConnection)

            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td

            recLocal.MoveNext

        Loop

    Else

    End If 'Empty recordset

    recLocal.Close
    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login"

Exit_cmdLogin:                          ' Label to resume after error.
      Exit Sub

Err_Login:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "SelectAll()")
    Resume Exit_cmdLogin

End Sub
```

Here are the 4 messages that popup with bad credentials in the order they appear:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

[image: Error 3]

[image: Error 4]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the Sub/Function of your VBA? The answer to your question lies within your error handling. My VBA is a little rusty, but you should be able to capture the specific err.Number and then handle it accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried error handler code? What I've read indicates SQLServer errors should be handled same as VBA errors. Your second 'message' looks like input form.

Comment: I added the code above, a little bit easier to read. This is what I typically write in to all objects. SO as you can see the 4th message is mine, the third is Access... it's the first two I need to suppress or remove programatically.

Comment: *I have a login form in Access that sends the username and pwd to an ODBC connection string to connect to a SQL Server* -- this is the code we need to see.

Comment: OK I added the entire sub

Answer (score 2):

To test User/Password, use a **QueryDef** beforehand to test the connection.
Don't try to create the linked table before that.

```vb
    ' Create a simple Pass-Through query
    Set qdf = dbCurrent.CreateQueryDef("")
    With qdf
        .Connect = strConnection
        .ReturnsRecords = True
        .Sql = "SELECT GETDATE() AS Test"

        ' Try to connect, this will raise a trappable ODBC error if User/Password are wrong
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rst = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Wrong User/Password."
            ' etc.
        End If
    End With

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of error handling i would use to try and capture both applications errors

```
If DBEngine.Errors.Count > 1 Then
    'ODBC Error
    For Each errany In DBEngine.Errors
        msgbox "ODBCExecute: Err# " & errany.Number & " raised by " _
         & errany.Source & ": " & errany.Description, _
         vbCritical, "cmdExecuteAttached()"
    Next errany
Else  'Access Error
    msgbox "ODBCExecute: Err# " & ERR.Number & " raised by " _
     & ERR.Source & ": " & ERR.Description, _
     vbCritical, "cmdExecuteAttached()"
End If

GoTo Exit_Sub
Resume
```